# when do sums of converging things not converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. If sequences $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$ in $X$, then $a_n + b_n \rightarrow a+ b$ since $\|a_n + b_n - (a+b)\| \leq \|a_n - a\| + \|b_n - b\|$ by the triangle inequality.

In what setting does $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$ not imply $a_n + b_n \rightarrow a+b$?

The reason for this question is that I'd like to show convergence of a sequence of discrete-in-space stochastic processes to a continuous-in-space stochastic process.

Comment: You can always put a weird topology on a vector space for which addition is not a continuous function. In your case, you can't use the topology arising by taking a basis of the topology to be generated by open balls (i.e. the norm topology) as addition is continuous there as you noted.

Comment: You’re relaxing the assumption of a vector space?

Comment: This would be more along the lines of leaving the topological vector space setting (those vector spaces for which addition and scalar multiplication are continuous—the topology put on these is the weakest topology for which those are continuous) than vector space setting as vector spaces do not a priori have anything to say about convergence and more generally topology.

Comment: If you have a metric, the sum of sequences will always converge to the sum of limits.

Comment: The only setting is when the topology is not compatible with the linear structure. See also Cameron Williams' comment.

Comment: So the addition/multiplication properties of vector spaces are necessary and sufficient for "convergence of sums of converging things" to hold? Or just the addition part?